# this.importTextData returns undefined

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to import data from a tab delimited text file into a PDF using javascript.  I am attempting to do this (testing just the first line, at least) through the JavaScript Console using the following code:

```
var blah = this.importTextData("/C/Users/sbarry/Desktop/abc123.txt", 0)
console.println(blah)
```

My text file looks like this:

```
First   Second
ABC 123
DEF 456
GHI 789
```

I made sure I had form fields labeled First and Second on my PDF and then executed my code.  The result is:

```
undefined
It runs successfully.
```

Under my preferences I have the checkbox "Enable JavaScript Actions" checked, and I have "Enable Safe Reading Mode" unchecked in order to overcome any security restrictions.  How can I make this work?

I am using Foxit PhantomPDF ver. 7.2.

Comment: What is the output in the Console when you run just the import command (without writing its result into the variable blah)? You should get a return code between -3 and +3. Also, what happens when your second argument to the import command is 1?

Comment: If I run the command without storing the return value, the console simply says "It runs successfully".  Changing the second argument to 1 or another arbitrary number still returns "undefined"

Comment: This string looks unknown to me; I may be wrong, but it seems that this string comes from another JavaScript action/function (maybe through a Calculate event somewhere else; you might find out more by showing all JavaScript, and searching for that string).

Comment: I suspect that it could have something to do with the fact that I am using Foxit rather than Acrobat, but honestly I have no clue.

Comment: Well, that's crucial information… Have you verified whether Foxit supports the importTextData() method at all?

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is very light regarding Foxit and JavaScript.  There is not a dedicated reference manual that I can find (I have been going by the Acrobat Javascript reference).  When I type this.importTextData into the javascript console, it shows up as a little predictive text type of option, so it SEEMS like it should be supported.  However, I found that I can do something like this.asdsddghdf and get the same return of "undefined", which makes me suspect that maybe the importTextData method is missing or unsupported somehow?

Comment: Actually, I am not even sure whether Foxit supports any JavaScript at all (but that could be the case only for the mobile version); I did ask their support about that some time ago; have to dig out that email. About "undefined" being returned in the Console: a function or a call can return some value or object (in a function you specify that with the return command). If the call or function does not explicitely return something, the returned value is "undefined". If a property is not defined (as you call with this.asdfadsf), the value of the property is "undefined" because it is so…

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I got a response from someone at the Foxit team.  Apparently their software recognized the function but is unable to implement it, so hopefully that will be addressed in the near future.  For now, I am going to be using `this.importAnFDF` by generating an FDF file from scratch. (NOTE: This function does not have a return value, unlike `this.importTextData`.)

For information on FDF file structure, see section 12.7.7 of this document:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

The easiest way to see what an FDF file requires is to export one from your PDF editing software, open it with notepad or something similar and edit the field names and values to whatever is appropriate for your PDF form.